# What does "logout" command do on MacOS terminal

Tags: macos

I accidentally ran command `logout` on MacOS terminal and this is the output:

```
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...      63 completed.

[Process completed]
```

I could not find any help on this command.
Could someone explain what has happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It terminates the shell (typically `bash` or `zsh`) running in a Terminal tab/windows.

Some background:

- Unix shells can run as login or as non-login shells (which has some implications on which configuration files are read at startup).
- On a standard macOS installation, each Terminal tab/window runs a login shell.
- To end the shell process, you can either run `logout`, `exit`, or simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

It is worth noting that if you don't know what a terminal command does it is possible to find information from the manpage.

So, to find out what the command logout does you can enter

> man logout

at the command prompt.

Comment: While true in general, running `man logout` doesn't provide a lot of information on macOS.